# 'Tiling' a graph in NetworkX

Tags: python, networking, graph, networkx

So, if I have a basic Graph created in NetworkX, is there a way to 'tile' it such that it kind of multiplies the graph many times? It would be good if they were still connected. I've tried some fcns like nx.Union() but it seems to overlay the graphs rather than multiplying it out many times. I can't find any fcns that seem to accomplish this, any ideas?

EDIT: Input would be a graph with maybe up to 50 nodes. Output would be that very same graph, but iterated n times (such that there's n50 nodes in output graph). I would like however, for the iterations of the original graph to be connected, so either overlaying some nodes (st output nodes'<'n50) or creating new edges to connect iterations (st output edges'>'n(input edges))

Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and explain what the output would be?  I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Joel, I have edited with a little more description!

Comment: I, for one, do not understand what you mean at all. Do you want to add new nodes to your existing graph? Do you want to add new edges?

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is nx.disjoint_union, which will let you add two graphs and give them distinct node values.

```
 def n_disjoint_unions(G, n):
     H = nx.Graph()
     for _ in range(n):
         H = nx.disjoint_union(H, nx.copy(G))
     return H
```

You will need to specify how you want to connect these new graphs however.

Comment: I am closer... I have [this](http://imgur.com/WSv6yYr) for n=3. Now, I'd like it so that all of these are connected, maybe with edges between them (or sharing a set of nodes). Is there a clever way to do that? I am considering looking at the degree centrality of the nodes within the loop and connecting them if they are sufficiently low.

Comment: @jdg You could pick one node in the original that will be connected to all the copies? But really, what is your goal here? That would help figure out the best option.

Comment: My goal is to basically make the network arbitrarily large, so we can test some connectivity algorithms. The reason the file needs to be connected, and large, is so that we can run some speed tests and see which one is best suited to a very large network... I've created a little algorithm that finds nodes with lowest connectivity degree and connects them to other ones, making a connected network. It seems to work ok but needs to be generalized... Any other approaches?